# No getting complete data using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Following is my Entity Structure;

```
class Question{}
class Answer {
    @ManyToOne
    Question q;
}
class Comment {
    @ManyToOne
    Answer a;
}
```

In order to get all the details for a question by questionId I am getting the following result using query

```
select * from Comment c 
right join Answer a on c.answer_id = a.id 
right join Question q on a.question_id = q.id
where q.id = 27
order by a.likes desc;
```

[There are Six rows]

```
'10', '2016-05-16 11:41:22', '0', 'I use pink so it should be pink.', '0', '2016-05-16 11:43:43', '0', '0', '1', NULL, '16', '159', NULL, NULL, '16', '2', '2016-05-16 11:33:51', '0', 'I use black so it should be black', '2', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL
'11', '2016-05-16 11:41:45', '0', 'What about CYAN. :p', '0', '2016-05-16 11:43:43', '0', '0', '1', NULL, '16', '159', NULL, NULL, '16', '2', '2016-05-16 11:33:51', '0', 'I use black so it should be black', '2', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL

'8', '2016-05-16 11:39:00', '0', 'And those factors are??', '0', '2016-05-16 11:43:42', '0', '0', '1', NULL, '15', '159', NULL, NULL, '15', '2', '2016-05-16 11:33:28', '0', 'This depends on many factors. Start noticing different mobile phones.', '1', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 12:10:03', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL
'9', '2016-05-16 11:40:28', '0', 'Color of the SUN', '0', '2016-05-16 11:43:43', '0', '0', '1', NULL, '15', '159', '8', NULL, '15', '2', '2016-05-16 11:33:28', '0', 'This depends on many factors. Start noticing different mobile phones.', '1', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 12:10:03', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL

NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '17', '0', '2016-05-16 11:34:55', '0', 'Not every company manufactures yellow mobile phone.', '1', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 12:10:18', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL

'12', '2016-05-16 11:42:15', '0', 'Thought Well', '0', '2016-05-16 11:43:43', '0', '0', '1', NULL, '18', '159', NULL, NULL, '18', '1', '2016-05-16 11:35:32', '0', 'It is similar to color of the cars you see on the road.', '0', '2016-05-16 11:37:24', '0', '1', '2016-05-16 11:43:27', '146', NULL, '27', NULL, '27', '4', '2016-05-16 11:30:28', '2016-05-16 11:31:01', '0', 'What is most preferred color', '9', '1', NULL, '2016-05-16 12:10:32', '146', NULL, NULL
```

So by doing that I'm also getting the data for the answers whose no of comments in zero. But when I'm using hibernate with my HQL

```
SELECT c FROM Comment c 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN c.answer a 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN a.question q
where q.id = :questionId";
```

I'm only getting only `5` rows due to which I'm missing out those answers which have no comments. Kindly help me out in getting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well write a Named query as well in this case since your sql is working correctly.

```
String sql = "select * from Comment c 
              right join Answer a on c.answer_id = a.id 
              right join Question q on a.question_id = q.id
              where q.id = :questionId
              order by a.likes desc";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Object.class);
query.setParameter("questionId", id);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: I tries that.. firing native queery using hibernate... but same output

Comment: I have just edited the query. Have you run the same query as above.

Comment: Yes I did the same

Comment: I think the problem here is for the 6th row, comment Id is null, so thats the reason you are not able to get it using Native query .

Comment: Yes and that's why I could not fetch those answers which does not have comments.